# Random grey dotted bars on monitor screen while using Brave browser

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, brave

I see something like below on my laptop monitor screen very randomly:

[image]

I can even scroll through my Windowed application and it stays at the same place. I'm wondering if my monitor hardware has some issue or it is OS specific issue. I don't see anything wrong in task manager related to resources:

[image]

**My device details**:

A personal computer (PC) - Dell (Inspiron 5559) laptop with CORE i3 processor having RADEON additional graphics card. I've a Window 7 operating system (OS) installed on the PC.

I saw on internet that people usually talk about black bars coming on the sides and it stays constant which is usually monitor hardware issue. In my case its shape is random and can come anywhere as you can see in the screenshot above. I first want to nail down if it is some setting/software issue or my monitor has some hardware problem. This will help me take subsequent actions.

**Update**: I diagnosed this further. This is Brave browser specific error only. My other apps work fine. I've updated the tags to reflect the same.

**Update 2**: Now I'm observing that Whenever I face this issue and refresh the page loaded in the browser by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> then those grey bars go away.

Comment: Try running Dell Hardware tests for your particular model, especially the screen tests

Comment: Thanks @John I realized that this is Brave browser specific issue. Till I've a resolution I'll use Chrome in the meantime. Not sure if it can be a Brave bug.

Comment: Can you uninstall Brave Browser to narrow it down to that?

Comment: I can validate that even without uninstalling Brave. The moment I switch to any other application or browser (e.g. Chrome) those grey bars aren't there at all.

Comment: Try running SFC /SCANNOW from an admin command prompt.  Restart and test.  If that does not work, try a Windows 7 Repair Install from the Windows 7 DVD. Boot from it and select Repair.  Now may be a good time to upgrade to Windows 10.